# How to realize the function of glPushName and glPopName

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

How can I realize the functiong of glPopName and glPopName  in openGL 3.x ?

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL-3 no longer has *SELECTION* mode. Practically no OpenGL implementation out there did selection mode with hardware acceleration. One always dropped into software emulation mode.

Instead you could implement one of those:

- Rendering each object with a different colour, used as an index. Then read back the area of interest, and after that re-render the scene as usual. This is as close to selection mode as it gets.
- Read back the depth buffer values in the area of interest, project back into world positions and determine from your scene data, which object is at the selected position.

Or completely without OpenGL:

- Implement a ray-scene intersection test. Use spatial subdivision structures like Octree or Kd trees for acceleration.

Comment: I would highlight that the *object name stack* shall be derived from the render object hierarchy by the application, so it can be detected only the "top" object. Sadly, the depth values for each object onto the stack is not known.

Comment: Think you for your answer.My expression is not accurate.I want to know ——In opengl 3.1 ,it  discarded glPopName, glPushName ，butTo achieve a similar function, what function or method to chose.

Comment: glPopNameand glPushName has been deprecated in the latest OpenGL APIs. What is it replaced with? If not replaced, how can I get a similar effect?

Comment: @yaya: OpenGL is meant to be a pure drawing API. Selecting stuff is not drawing stuff, thus it has been removed. You're now expected to implement this yourself with application specific methods. I gave you 3 options how to do it.